# how to modify arguments in c program to pass it to another one?

Tags: c

I have a program, which implements its functionality by exploiting another one. The only thing I need to do is appropriately modify its arguments. The problem is, when I execute another program, I never return to the original one. Therefore, using malloc to allocate space for modified strings will cause memory leak. What do? The program look like this:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argv[1] = ...
    argv[2] = ...
    ...
    exec("/bin/echo", argv);
}
```

`argv[1], argv[2]` are, for example, the same original strings but with some appended characters, so they need memory extension

Comment: No it won't cause a memory leak. When `exec` is called it replaces the original address space with the new one. That includes reclaiming any dynamic memory by the OS. So go ahead and use `malloc` with abandon.

Comment: @kaylum thanks, nice to know

Comment: make sure that the `argv[the-last-one] = NULL;`